# Relationship between productivity and GDP

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, productivity

I was looking at the OECD data for GDP per hour worked as a stand in for productivity and was extremely confused when I started comparing the numbers and tried to understand the relationship between GDP, productivity and working hour for Turkey.

In 2013 Turkey had a GDP per hour worked of \$40.5. The average worker worked 1,832 hours. The employment rate in the country was 49.5% and it's GDP per capita was $22,373 (all 2015 dollars).

However, when you do the following calculation

```
productivity * hours per worker * employment = GDP per capita
```

you get \$36,727.02 not $22,372.

Am I completely misunderstanding what these figures actually mean?

Comment: can you please provide link to the statistics you used for your calculations?

Comment: GDP per capita typically means economic output per person and is calculated by dividing the GDP of a country by its population.  In your calculations, you are using employment variables.   The population levels and the employment levels of any specific country will most likely be different.